# Converting a string to a double or float to execute math equation

Tags: c, string, floating-point, type-conversion, double

I have a function that I am trying to convert from PHP. I am executing the function like this example:

```
latlong_hex("1234.5678N");
```

and I need the result to be processed but I am running into problems with the string to double conversion and the calculations. After the conversion, I am losing all numbers after the decimal. The HEX function at the bottom is working fine.

```
int latlong_hex(char* gps_coord)
{
    int gps_result;
    char direction[2] = {0};
    char gps_latlong[10] = {0};
    double latdeg;
    double tempDec;
    char* tempGPS;

    strncpy(gps_latlong, gps_coord, 9);
    strncpy(direction, gps_coord+9, 1);

    tempDec = strtod(gps_latlong, NULL);
    free(gps_latlong);

    tempDec = tempDec / 100;

    if(direction == 'W' || direction == 'S')latdeg = round((floor(tempDec)+((tempDec - floor(tempDec))/60),7))*-1;
    else latdeg = round((floor(tempDec) + ((tempDec - floor(tempDec))/60),7));
    if(latdeg > 0){
        gps_result = latdeg / 0.0000001;
    }
    else{
        gps_result = (4294967295 + (latdeg/0.0000001))  ;
    }

    dec_hex(gps_result);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What is `gps_result` ? It's not declared anywhere in your code. My crystal ball tells me that it is declared as `int gps_result`. And please show us `dec_hex` even if you think it is working fine.

Comment: `strncpy(gps_latlong, gps_coord, 9); strncpy(direction, gps_coord+9, 1);` -----> `char direction = gps_coord[9]; strncpy(gps_latlong, gps_coord, 8);`

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
free(gps_latlong);
```

is instant undefined behavior, since `gps_latlong` is not a heap-allocated object. Remove that line.

Also, you should call `strtod()` directly on `gps_coord`, the local copying serves no purpose.

Comment: gps_latlong is extracting the number out of the string that includes letters that are not needed.

Comment: @Eddie But `strtod()` won't care, if you give it "1.2FOO" it will find `1.2` and stop at the `F`. There's no point in juggling around the string, when you're still going to hand it to `strtod()`. In fact, look up the use for the second argument (the one you've set to `NULL`).